# Why I believe the Fanatic badge should be canceled/reformulated

Tags: discussion

I believe the Fanatic badge in its current form should not exist, for the following two reasons:

1. Socially, people should not be encouraged to work consecutively for 100 days. On the contrary, a person should take a several days off work every once in a while, go on vacation, do sports, fish, spend time with his/her loved ones etc. Is it really commendable that he/she is sneaking over to their laptops to check out SO?
2. The badges page says:

   > Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.

   Merely visiting the site is not a contribution to the community, in itself (as opposed to being consistently *active* on the site). This goes for Enthusiast as well, by the way.

**Edit:** Also, I do not believe there is any benefit to the community in members being active on *consecutive* days, in itself. I mean, if you're active every other day of a year, or for half a year consecutively then not at all, it's not clear the latter is more beneficial than the former. The only potential benefit might be your answering question'ish comments faster but that would be another badge altogether.

Instead of Fanatic (or perhaps even Fanatic and Enthusiast), an alternative *could* be something like "Made a contribution (which was not deleted/closed/undone) on at least X days over the course of Y days". Enthusiast could be, say, **Edit:** X=40 Y=60, and Fanatic could be X=150 Y=200. By "could" I mean also "could be something else or nothing at all".

**Notes:**

- The comment by @GoBusto does, I believe, emphasizes my point, as do questions such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-%C3%9Cber-fanatic-badge?lq=1) etc.

Comment: "Socially, people should not be encouraged to work consecutively for 100 days" - the badge is about _visiting_ the site. It's enough to have it in a pinned tab in your browser, as long as you open your browser for a hundred consecutive days. Thus your first point is entirely invalid.

Comment: Eh, that wouldn't work @l4mpi. You have to visit the site and _do something_.

Comment: Speaking as someone who recently got the Fanatic badge, I'd like to point out that point 1 assumes that I have any sort of social life to begin with (I have no interest in vacation-ing, sports, fishing, or human beings, so it's not like I'd spend the time doing one of those other things anyway).

Comment: @l4mpi That's because the exact definition of "do something" isn't really known: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731

Comment: And a more recent statement that not just anything counts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/ @l4mpi

Comment: Ok, then "do something" basically means "click any link". I'm pretty sure just opening a single question counts, so my first comment could be amended to have a specific question open in a pinned tab instead of the front page. Although I'm rather sure that I days count as visited where I didn't access anything else than the front page.

Comment: @l4mpi Just having a page open in a pinned tab won't work.  You have to do something (even if only clicking a link) once per UTC day. [Trust](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/fanatic?userid=25936) [me](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/fanatic?userid=25936)[,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/fanatic?userid=162704) [I'm](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic?userid=739) [a](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic?userid=48) [fanatic.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic?userid=99456)

Comment: I agree. It should be reformulated. For Stack Overflow, it should read "1000 consecutive days", not "100". (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-2048-days-2048-consecutive-in-his-her-profile).

Comment: @l4mpi: If what you say is true/were true, that would make the badge even more pointless: "Thank you for keeping us in your browser tabs"...

Comment: @einpoklum more seriously, I was making your point about contribution vs. visit in 2010: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-%C3%9Cber-fanatic-badge?lq=1#comment138846_58456

Comment: @l4mpi Just logging in is already far too much on a special day. Astonishingly, many of the meta users do not seem to have any empathy for this, which sheds a dimmed light on the meta community. To me, this is so ovbiously a bad approach that I wonder why it needs discussion at all and your point is entirely invalid.

Comment: It is a game, why are so serious about this 'badge' thing? Should StackOverflow cure every evil in the world?

Comment: @Steve: Game-runners have some responsibility for the well-being of game participants IMO.

Comment: yes, @Steve, the badges should try to avoid some evil here. Because I really think it is a bit evil to simply offer that incentive at all, drawing many people into this who lose a little part of their traditions. Call me naive, and I would still say it, and that is why I started the opposing comments at all. It is not so much a game anymore when it incentivises users to actions reducing some basics of culture and social life. It would also be a good sign of SO just to change it to 5/7 or 6/7 week approach in respect of culture and social life.

Comment: @Lorenz sorry but I can't take your post seriously. Logging in is "far too much"? How long does it take to grab you smartphone, navigate to stackoverflow.com, log in, and click a question? That shouldn't take longer than two or three minutes, and I would suggest that anybody who thinks investing three minutes per day is too much should not be titled a "fanatic". And that's even before we consider the fact that nobody is forcing anyone to get this badge and it has literally zero value outside of bragging rights on SO...

Comment: I disagree here strongly. It is a principle. There should be the normal special days of the week and of the year in everyone's life (or those days should be possible at least), where even thinking of SO is already too much to be "obligatory" in the form of a monitored incentive system like these SO badges imply. To the point: It could decrease someone's "National Holiday feeling" - let us exaggerate it a bit - by 50 %, if she **must** care about an everyday thing then for a second. She might not even notice this.

Comment: @Lorenz so.... Not a fanatic, then? I visit stack during downtime. I like to browse the questions on world builder or rpg or arcade, and I make sure to start my daily visits from stack, so the login can count. The whole point of the badge is to 'reward' ppl who keep stack at the **top** of their mind, *above anything else*. From that definition... How is it 'evil' to not recognize... You know ... 'non fanatics'?

Comment: @Payrice Every badge point is a benchmark at first sight. The questioned badges seduce members, putting up some pressure beyond the positive reciprocal altruism. Think of it from an outside perspective, *you easily fall for it* as it comes in small steps, and once you have a quarter by accident, you try the full. A general 5- or 6-day rule can add a happy feeling to newcomers and marathoners (leaving aside the bad ‘fanatic’). Everyone is free to login everyday: How is it 'evil' to not recognize 1-2 days of the week if this is not about badge hunting but about the free will and interest?

Answer (score 8):

1. Like @l4mpi said, you don't need to do any actual "work" each day. You just need to be logged in and view some questions. (please note that the specifics of this isn't disclosed, but viewing a couple questions is likely more than enough to be counted as a day.. if you want to be extra sure, do a review or two and a vote or two, just so you have some evidence you visited that day)
2. The reason it's a gold badge, is that it is *fairly* hard to accomplish. If we made it easier it should not be a gold badge anymore.

Comment: I don't think we even need to view questions because I just took my code review profile and it showed the you have been logged in at the top, and, a day has been added. Similarly, whenever I visit my Profile page ( even if I don't view any question before that ) a day is added .

Comment: @ArunA.S, perhaps that is telling you that going to your profile counts as doing something...

Comment: @Andy , that's what I actually meant, but sorry that I did not make it clear earlier.

Comment: So, 1. You're not doing any work, just maintaining the warm fuzzy feeling of reading SO? Meh... I don't really buy that.  2. I didn't suggest it's easy to accomplish, I argued it does not constitute a contribution.

Comment: It is not right to say just be logged in is nothing much. This action alone is already too much to ask for if you had any cultural empathy for those people who care for a clear cut from everyday when they cherish their special days. Gold badge or bronze, it does simply not matter, it is for sure not an honourful approach of this community and your answer is the clear symbol of it. Both points 1 and 2 leave me astonished.

Comment: You don't even have to view anything, I put all of the SE sites I'm in (links to my profile) into a bookmark folder and shift-click it once a day and that doesn't reset my progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the Fanatic badge on several SO sites. There is nothing more frustrating than being around day 92 and you miss a day and get to start all over again. However I suppose it builds character much like swimming across the English Channel to visit France during the winter.

Personally I think it is wonderful practice for developing the kind of methodically compulsive mindset that can lead to being a great coder or a great tester.

What I found was that I had to be logged in, visit the site twice a day (once in the morning and once in the evening as my impression is the once a day criteria seems to be have some randomness to it which led to having to start over a time or two), look at some questions, do a vote or two, leave a comment or two, maybe answer a question, or edit a post.

So working on the Fanatic badge also lets you work on several of the others as well.

Comment: It's not "random", but I'm pretty sure it _is_ based on UTC, so if you live away from that time zone, what counts as a full day passing to you might not count as a full day passing to the system. For example, if you live in UTC+8, alternately checking at 8:30 and 7:30 will make it look like you're skipping days, because you do two checks in one UTC "day", then none the next, then two...

Comment: You should question more what you get served.

Answer (score -16):

Badges that ignore Sundays and national Holidays are, probably among many other similar laws over the world, against the Article 139 of the German Constitution of 1919, which is integrated in Article 140 [Law of religious denominations] of the Basic Law for the Federal Republic of Germany:

**"Sunday and holidays recognised by the state shall remain protected by law as days of rest from work and of spiritual improvement."**

See:
https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0889 coming from https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0825

And it also is against the 4th Commandment:

**Remember the Sabbath day to keep it holy.**

Religous or not, those commandments are quite mirroring a basic trait of the worldwide cultures and they are directly valid for 3 world religions.
Thus, the badges are discriminating.

And yes, looking at SO can be seen as an action of work, as the special days are meant to rest and be different, even if it is just fun to use SO, I agree. It is more About the minority for which it is just mentally bad not to separate a special day from the normal days (this can happen to anyone, please do not laugh about it). I am asking everyone for more empathy here. Just **having** to think of SO at all on a special day goes already too far for some, and it would not harm anyone to take away one day per week from the calculation, as a sign of respect for the human cultures in general. and if the badges stay like this, this is just disappointing, for I do not see the great issue here not to change this, and it would create just a nice sign for all, it is a clear win and no-lose for the community.

Comment: I wonder how I could contact someone official of this website about this sensitive issue. Discussing it here has a clear (and obviously wrong) result. If someone knows, please help. Thank you.

Comment: I have read both of your answers. Neither of them shows how these badges harm people who do not wish to participate daily. They're not required by any stretch, they are fun - no one is required to think about SO every day and I'd guess that many of the people who earn these badges are unaware of them until they are earned. If someone has religious or personal reasons for not using the site daily, there's no negative impact should they avoid the sites on some number of days. One could even argue that the badge is an indication to some that they might want to slow down and disconnect.

Comment: @Catija Did you read their question as well https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398079/change-badges-that-reward-activity-on-x-days-in-a-row-to-always-exclude-2-days-o

Comment: Not sure if trolling... The cited part of the german constitution is for protecting employees from their employers. It has nothing to do with recreational activities on a sunday, and visiting a website is very much a recreational activity unless somebody pays you for it. You're allowed - or were, before corona - to volunteer as a helper for public events on sundays (e.g. being a steward for a marathon, which is actual unpaid work in cooperation with the city authorities). If you think a SO badge requirement is against the constitution then most everyday activities would be illegal on a sunday.

Comment: @Catija, I see a problem in the pure incentive of it. Human beeings are weak and are easily seduced to actions they actually cannot oversee themselves. That is why even the incentive should be dealt as if it was a forced thing. I understand your point, but at that stage of 30 or 100 days in a row, the majority knows enough about badges, and the incentives leads them to a few too many actions. Every human beeing should at least have the chance to have one rest day per week. He can still login on SO of course, but then without this incentive, to protect those who need rest without knowing it.

Comment: Although I want to stress that it is not about me, but about a general discrimination, I can tell you my own experience here. At 15 days out of 30, I came to see the badge, accidentally, in the monitoring.When I had 20 of 30 days, I forgot to login, but for a reason. It was on the 2nd day of Pentacost National Holiday, best weather, picknick, walks, "the birds sang nicely" aso., I forgot to login. And I felt afterwards like just one single login at that day would have decreased my life quality at this special day. From that I came to think of the minorities and the ones that are seduced.

Comment: @l4mpi There is barely anything in our whole life that sticks a monitored incentive to 30 or 100 days. You can work on Sundays if you decide so, and important jobs have exceptions, I regard this. It is not about work or free will here, as I see a seduction of some people here to lose some basic principle which we can see over all the world, and again, also a discrimination against those who are already Aware of the issue.

Comment: @Lorenz "I felt afterwards like just one single login at that day would have decreased my life quality at this special day" - then congratulations for keeping your quality of life up. It does however mean you're not a "fanatic", because a fanatic would log in every hour or so to check if they had new replies or votes etc. If you're arguing this is inherently a bad thing, then you should campaign for the whole website to be shut down, because the incentives from gamification are the whole reason this community got going.

Comment: @l4mpi again, it is not about me, this is just the story how I came to think of it all. It could happen to me that I get that badge without knowing it. But at some days, you just should have a special feeling for something else, I mean potentially even if one does not yet know it at all. And: I agree, that the word fanatic is not a nice word to me. Though I like to work on SO mostly everyday with quite some interest and some fun as well.

Answer (score -23):

I would not only criticise the fanatic badges, but rather all badges that need daily activity on the row over time, like also enthusiast, daily reputation badges, and there might be other badges or badges to come in this sense.

Getting them means to "work"/think/act as everyday on religious and traditional days, weekend days and national holidays, and generally holdidays, no time off. Think of birthdays, family days and all other private events. I know so many people who cherish such important days which then take an important part of their life quality. The badges are a sort of discrimination against them.
Think of a Jew who might like to take a complete time off on a Saturday, a Christian who wants to holy a special holy day or the Sunday or a Muslim who needs the same mental time off on Friday, and there are so many other similar days for the peoples of the world. Think of those nationals who want to have a mental time off for their nation on a national holiday.

I do not want to say that taking part in SO might not be of value everyday, and still, having such a batch is not right in my eyes. Even if you like SO everyday and the miracle of reciprocal altruism here, an everyday incentive is culturally sensitive and gives me a cold feeling about the community - in this point only, though badge hunting in general is already a bit of a grayzone.

I do not want to be judging morally, as I almost got this badge accidentally and thus I got to know about it at all. Yet, I recommend changing those badges to have 2 days in a week as possible SO-free days.

Those who really care for some completely different days in their life also add value to their society and their own life standard. It would be a sign of respect for the cultures of the people, and an empathic signal, if SO would change those badges to add this freedom of 2 days per week and then just prolong the badge requirement by those dropped days or a little further.

Comment: You mean like normal people also have "no mobile phone"-days and "not using my computer"-days? To be honest, I think the badges should be changed to "Enthusiast" for 30 consecutive days, "Addict" for 100 consecutive days, and "Fanatic" for 365 consecutive days.

Comment: Yes, some people have a no mobile phone day once a week, though I do not belong to them. But I do not laugh about them. I know that cherishing special days adds to your life quality. I just have more empathy for this life style, and it is important to respect that even if one does not understand it fully. Think of being at your friend's wedding, and you need to check the stock market because of day trading and you need to log in on SO for a badge. Cold, very cold.

Comment: That is not cold at all. If one does not log in because something else was more important then one is **not** fanatic.

Comment: I said this on another comment thread, but I figure I'll repeat it so it's more visible.  If you have 30 seconds to check your phone - even on those special days, you have time to check Stack Overflow.  Additionally, the day always cuts over based on UTC, so depending on where you live, you can be on Stack Overflow at a time which wouldn't qualify as a time when you want to disconnect but still have it count as the next day.  A true fanatic would be plotting this stuff out, y'know? 

Comment: @Makoto hey repeating things on this does not harm too much, i can also say it again. I doubt that the fanatic is then a good incentive at all, if it means to log in on public holidays when you mentally take a day off for the love of your culture, or speaking of minorities that have weekly days off. It would not harm anyone to change to a 5 out of 7 week days approach, while the current badges lead some people to a behaviour that is not good for the soul. The human being has weaknesses, and such badges directly imply a disregard of special days. The enthusiast badge has the general problem.

Comment: @Lorenz The point is that the days need to be **consecutive**. There's no requirement that you earn this badge or any other badges for that matter. If your religion or soul-heath prevents you from logging in, then you will just not earn the badge. And I don't see why you should, since it doesn't say "almost consecutive" or "5 out of 7". Nobody deceived you. I'm even fairly sure that some users have had to redo this because they lost their internet-connection on the last day. Maybe not having internet everyday is not good for the soul for them.

Comment: There's another badge that only requires participation over a year. There's no requirement that one logs in regularly. It's the [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) where you have to be an "Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation". This seems to fit your requirements for being able to take time-outs from Stack Overflow.

Comment: What I think we're arriving at here @Lorenz is that you're not interested in being a fanatic.  I'm cool with that; please don't try to numb or reduce the level of fanaticism required to achieve that goal.  You haven't done enough to convince me that, just because someone wants to take a day off of the Internet, that the badge's requirements should be slackened to accommodate those people, and I'm no longer interested in any further debate on the matter.  Either you want to participate at a fanatic's level or you don't.  There's nothing more to this.

Comment: @Scrattle misunderstanding, that is not strict enough. I do understand the reason for the enthusiastic and fanatic badge. It is to keep the good participants on the site as much as possible, which adds to motivation. And I simply criticise that these badges are culturally and socially discriminating and not sensitive to special days that everyone should have sometimes in 30 or 100 days, and there is little less fanatism if you take out one day in a week. When I say 2 days, you can discuss that, that is not the point here. We could still speak of consecutive days then, with one break a week.

Comment: @Makato I doubt that a fanatism should be incentivised where it harms some wide-spread basic traditions of many cultures. I just have a clear empathy for keeping-days-special-people, and I have little personal experience as well, though it is not just about me. I still could get that badge accidentally some day without even knowing about it, as I usually work on something research intensive everyday at the moment. To make you laugh, I have "lost" it on day 20 of 30 after I had enjoyed 
Pentecost national holiday, forgetting about SO. Which gave me the idea of writing all of this here.